Question about proof of Proposition 11.36.(c) in Lee:s "Intro to Topological Manifolds".
Loosely paraphrased, here is the statement of prop. 11.36.(c) in Lee:s "Introduction to Topological Manifolds":

Let $q_1:E_1 \to X$ and $q_2:E_2 \to X$ be covering maps. Then every covering homomorphism $\varphi:E_1 \to E_2$ is itself a covering map.

The proof first shows that $\varphi$ is surjective, and then comes the part where I get lost (loosely paraphrased):

Let $U$ be the component of $q_2^{-1}(V)$, where $V$ is the intersection $U_1 \cap U_2$ of neighborhoods $U_1,U_2 \subseteq X$ evenly covered by $q_1,q_2$ respectively, and containing a point $x \in X$ such that $q_2(e) = x$. We need to show that the components of $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ are mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $\varphi$. Consider the restrictions of $q_1$ and $\varphi$ to "stack of pancakes" $q_1^{-1}(V)$. Since $U$ is both open and closed in $q_2^{-1}(V)$, it follows that $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is both open and closed in $q_1^{-1}(V)$, and is thus a union of components, by problem 4.12 (in Lee). On any such component $U_{\alpha}$, we have that $q_1|_{U_{\alpha}} = q_2 \circ \varphi|_{U_{\alpha}}$, and $q_1,q_2$ are both homeomorphisms on $U_{\alpha}$, so therefore $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.


The main thing I don't think I understand, is why $q_2$ is a homeomorphism on $\varphi(U_{\alpha})$?
I also find it weird that they talk about the components of $\varphi^{-1}(U)$; or perhaps I interpreted this wrongly as saying that we know that $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of components, perhaps what is meant is just that we can assume that the components of $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ with the subspace topology partition $\varphi^{-1}(U)$. It seems like they later actually show that $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union (when Lee says that it is a union of components). Or well, the two statements are identical, since the components partition $\varphi^{-1}(U)$, $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is of course a disjoint union of its components.

I am most interested in understanding the first bulletpoint above (I think I figured out the second one).

So, I think I realized the answer (to my main question). We know that $q_2|_{U}:U \to V$ is a homeomorphism, and $\varphi(U_{\alpha}) \subseteq U$, since $U_{\alpha} \subseteq \varphi^{-1}(U)$ and $\varphi$ is surjective so we have $\varphi(U_{\alpha}) \subseteq \varphi(\varphi^{-1}(U)) = U$. The restriction of a homeomorphism is a homeomorphism, so $q_2|_{\varphi(U_{\alpha})}$ is a homeomorphism.
